# Form submit button state changes on selection, but not correct on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jquery script that disables the submit button of a form when no valid option is selected.

This works if the page loads with the 'Select a procedure...' option selected. However, some pages load with prepopulated values, and as such.. the submit button loads as disabled.

```
$("#sidebar-before-after-select").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "xx") {
        $("#sidebar-before-after-submit").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#sidebar-before-after-submit").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

How can this be adjusted so it reads the current value on page load, as well as change?

Comment: trigger the change event on your select input element on every page load.

Comment: $("#sidebar-before-after-select").trigger('change');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function setDisabled() {
   if ($("#sidebar-before-after-select").val() == "xx") {
       $("#sidebar-before-after-submit").prop("disabled", true);
   } else {
       $("#sidebar-before-after-submit").prop("disabled", false);
   }
}

$(function() {
   setDisabled();

   $("#sidebar-before-after-select").change(function () {
       setDisabled();
   });
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. I'll accept this in 5 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Call your function on docready and on change. See below:

```
<script>
      $(function(){
           checkSelect();
           $("#sidebar-before-after-select").change(function() {
                 checkSelect();
            }):
        }):

      checkSelect function(){
        if ( $("#sidebar-before-after-submit option:selected").val() == "xx") {
              $("#sidebar-before-after-submit").prop("disabled", true);
          } 
         else {
              $("#sidebar-before-after-submit").prop("disabled", false);
          }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: HI, although this answer came first, I can't accept it as it wouldn't fit in correctly , and had markup issues (I think partly my fault, because this is going inside a JS file, and not in `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //you can trigger the change event in dom ready.
  $(function(){
   $("#sidebar-before-after-select").trigger("change");
 });
```

Comment: Please expand on why you think this will help.